# Can't start service zimbra on heartbeat

Tags: centos, vmware-workstation, zimbra, heartbeat

i want to start zimbra service with heartbeat on haresource file. but it cant start zimbra service after boot. im using centOs, this is my haresource file:

```
node1.lol.net IPaddr::192.168.1.99/24/eth0:0 zimbra
```

Comment: im using vmware workstation 9

Comment: it's better if you use pacemaker, if you are starting with a new project.